# Are the "Great Supper of God" and the "Wedding Supper of the Lamb" the same event?

Tags: eschatology, revelation, feasts

In Revelation 19, there is a feast or feasts mentioned by two names.

The first is *The Wedding Supper of the Lamb*:

> ibid. vv. 7-9 (NASB): Let us rejoice and be glad and give the glory to Him, for the marriage of the Lamb has come and His bride has made herself ready.” It was given to her to clothe herself in fine linen, bright and clean; for the fine linen is the righteous acts of the saints.
>
> Then he said to me, “Write, ‘Blessed are those who are invited to the marriage supper of the Lamb.’” And he said to me, “These are true words of God.” Then I fell at his feet to worship him. But he said to me, “Do not do that; I am a fellow servant of yours and your brethren who hold the testimony of Jesus; worship God. For the testimony of Jesus is the spirit of prophecy.”

This seems to be paralleled in Isaiah, where the Lord prepares a feast of choice meats and fine wines:

> Isaiah 25:6-8 (NASB) The Lord of hosts will prepare a lavish banquet for all peoples on this mountain;
> A banquet of aged wine, choice pieces with marrow,
> And refined, aged wine.
> And on this mountain He will swallow up the covering which is over all peoples,
> Even the veil which is stretched over all nations.
> He will swallow up death for all time,
> And the Lord God will wipe tears away from all faces,
> And He will remove the reproach of His people from all the earth;
> For the Lord has spoken.
> And it will be said in that day,
> “Behold, this is our God for whom we have waited that He might save us.
> This is the Lord for whom we have waited;
> Let us rejoice and be glad in His salvation.”

The second feast in Revelation 19 is *The Great Supper of God*:

> ibid. vv. 17-21 (NASB) Then I saw an angel standing in the sun, and he cried out with a loud voice, saying to all the birds which fly in midheaven, “Come, assemble for the great supper of God, so that you may eat the flesh of kings and the flesh of commanders and the flesh of mighty men and the flesh of horses and of those who sit on them and the flesh of all men, both free men and slaves, and small and great.”
>
> And I saw the beast and the kings of the earth and their armies assembled to make war against Him who sat on the horse and against His army.
>
> And the beast was seized, and with him the false prophet who performed the signs in his presence, by which he deceived those who had received the mark of the beast and those who worshiped his image; these two were thrown alive into the lake of fire which burns with brimstone. And the rest were killed with the sword which came from the mouth of Him who sat on the horse, and all the birds were filled with their flesh.

This text in verses Revelation 19:17-21 closely parallels those of Ezekiel 39:

> Ezekiel 39:17-21 “As for you, son of man, thus says the Lord God, ‘Speak to every kind of bird and to every beast of the field, “Assemble and come, gather from every side to My sacrifice which I am going to sacrifice for you, as a great sacrifice on the mountains of Israel, that you may eat flesh and drink blood. You will eat the flesh of mighty men and drink the blood of the princes of the earth, as though they were rams, lambs, goats and bulls, all of them fatlings of Bashan. So you will eat fat until you are glutted, and drink blood until you are drunk, from My sacrifice which I have sacrificed for you. You will be glutted at My table with horses and charioteers, with mighty men and all the men of war,” declares the Lord God. “And I will set My glory among the nations; and all the nations will see My judgment which I have executed and My hand which I have laid on them."

Ezekiel also condemns Gog and Magog by name in this chapter, and so it is reasonable to conclude that *The Great Supper of God* is the feast by wild animals on the slain warriors of Gog and Magog described in Revelation 20. Chronologically, Revelation 20 places these events immediately after the thousand year reign of Messiah:

> Revelation 20:7-10 (NASB) When the thousand years are completed, Satan will be released from his prison, and will come out to deceive the nations which are in the four corners of the earth, Gog and Magog, to gather them together for the war; the number of them is like the sand of the seashore. And they came up on the broad plain of the earth and surrounded the camp of the saints and the beloved city, and fire came down from heaven and devoured them. And the devil who deceived them was thrown into the lake of fire and brimstone, where the beast and the false prophet are also; and they will be tormented day and night forever and ever.

It seems unreasonable to conclude that the blessed who are invited to *The Wedding Supper of the Lamb* are the same as the animals who are invited to *The Great Supper of God*, and that the corpses of the dead are the same as the choice meats and fine wine, so the two events seem distinct, however, I have recently read some comments in which the two events are conflated.

**Are *The Wedding Supper of the Lamb* and *The Great Supper of God* one in the same, or are they different events?**

Comment: This seems like a well researched question that effectively answers itself with "*It seems unreasonable to conclude that ...*".  But it ends by presenting the actual reason for even thinking of the question as "_I have recently read some comments in which the two events are conflated_".  What are those comments, and why did the  commentators think the two events were the same?

Answer (score 1):

I searched for evidence of any religious group conflating the two feasts. I found one group that taught that Isaiah 25:6-8 spoke of a literal millennial on earth (still future) where there would be a thousand-year feast of literal food and drink for all humans living on the earth then (*Isaiah's Prophecy*, Vol. 1 pp273-4, published in 2000) But in its 15 April 2000 journal, it identified the Revelation 19 event as God's war against the ungodly nations and kings, prior to that millennial rule of Christ (*The Watchtower* p.12). This shows a clear distinction. It also said in an older book that Revelation 19 speaks of the destruction of the devil's visible political organization, with that feasting on their flesh paralleling Isaiah 63:1-7 (not 25:6-8). But it took the view that that gory feast has to happen first (on earth) before the survivors and those resurrected on to earth can begin to enjoy the literal feast of good food and drink thereafter. It also seemed to indicate the wedding supper of the Lamb would happen in heaven at the end of the thousand years, and nobody on earth would partake of that.

Other groups that don't take the literal millennial rule on earth interpretation still don't say the two feasts are the same. The Revelation makes a clear distinction, no matter how you interpret it.  If this was all about one feast or supper, why would the Revelation not state that? Everything it says shows a first event, with a gory feast for birds and beasts (which need not be literal), only after which can there be the wedding supper of the Lamb with his bride, in heaven. Don't forget that 2 Peter ch. 3 speaks of the old heaven and earth being removed and replaced with a new heaven and earth, in which righteousness will dwell. The great supper of God relates to the old systems being destroyed by him, while the wedding supper of the Lamb speaks of the new systems then in place.

I dare say that a huge amount of research could uncover one group or other that conflates the two feasts, but if you have read such an interpretation, you could save us all a lot of time by giving your sources!